# Creating Angular2 component/directive wrapper for Dygraphs

Tags: angular, dygraphs

I have an existing AngularJS application which uses a directive to 'wrap' the DyGraphs JavaScript library and that works well.

However, I'm investigating migration to Angular2 and am struggling to create an Angular2 component (or directive) to wrap DyGraphs and have been unable to find any targeted help.

I've looked at similar charting libraries and how these have been wrapped and attempted to do the same with DyGraphs but hit a number of hurdles.

I'd be grateful for any advice on how to proceed with this task as it's likely that we'll need to wrap a number of other JS libraries including several from Vis in the near future.

Many thanks in advance.

Update

Further to Thierry's great answer, I've refactored the code as shown below:

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Application</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <!-- dygraph -->
    <script src="node_modules/dygraphs/dygraph-combined.js"></script>   
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>

  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app> 
  </body>
</html>
```

app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DygraphComponent } from './dygraph.component'; 
@Component({
  template: `
    <dygraph [title]="title"></dygraph>
  `,
  directives: [ DygraphComponent ] 
})
export class AppComponent {
  title:string = 'some title';
}
```

app/dygraph.component.ts:

```
import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var Dygraph:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'dygraph',
  template: `
    <div #graph></div>
  `
})
export class DygraphComponent implements  AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('graph')
  elt:ElementRef;

  @Input()
  title:string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    new Dygraph(this.elt.nativeElement, "data.txt", {});

  }

}
```

However, when I try to run the code, I get a 404 error on traceur. Any suggestions on how to resolve this very gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement such component with inputs and the `@ViewChild` decorator this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dygraph',
  template: `
    <div #graph></div>
  `
})
export class DygraphComponent {
  @ViewChild('graph')
  elt:ElementRef;

  @Input()
  title:string;

  (...)

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new Dygraph(this.elt.nativeElement, "ny-vs-sf.txt", {
      legend: this.legend,
      title: this.title,
      (...)
    });
  }
}
```

Then add the directive in the `directives` attribute of the component you want to use it and define the element:

```
@Component({
  tempalte: `
    <dygraph [title]="title"></dygraph>
  `,
  directives: [ DygraphComponent ] 
})
export class SomeComponent {
  title:string = 'some title';
}
```

Comment: I've implement your code and added:

dygraph.component.ts:

import { Component, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

app.component.ts:

import { Component, DygraphComponent } from './dygraph.component';

and included:

    <script src="node_modules/dygraphs/dygraph-combined.js"></script>

in index.html.

However, I get the following errors:

app/dygraph.component.ts: error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Dygraph'.
app/app.component.ts: error TS2305: Module '"./app/dygraph.component"' has no exported member 'Component'.

Comment: in fact, it's at compilation level. There are two options here. You could add this: `declare var Dygraph:any` or install typings for the library if exists (`typings install library-name`)...

Comment: Excellent. Thanks Thierry. By including the declare var line in dygraph.component.ts, the first issue is resolved. However, I get the following still: Module '"F:/angular2/dygraphs2/app/dygraph.component"' has no exported member 'Component'.  It's unclear why this is. I'm not exporting Component but then don't expect to be.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please ignore last comment. Found that issue. Will provide an update shortly.

Comment: Thanks again Thierry. Progress! But, still hitting issues. The latest is evident in the Console: zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found). Any suggestions on how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: many thanks for your help to date. Are you able to provide some more guidance on the issue I'm encountering please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the path of your ny-vs-sf.txt file? i cannot provide the path in my case