# Angular5: Dygraph is not defined in runtime

Tags: angular5, dygraphs

Using Angular 5 combined with dygraphs library, in runtime I receive an error: 'Dygraph is not defined', although dygraphs library is installed.

component.ts file:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var Dygraph: any;

@Component({
...
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      let div = document.getElementById('divId');
      new Dygraph(div, "Time,Value\n", {});
  }
}
```

component.html file:

```
<div id="divId"></div>
```

package.json file:

```
 "dependencies": {
    ...
    "dygraphs": "^2.1.0",
  },
```

Is it possible to use pure dygraphs with Angular2+ ? There is ng-dygraphs library, but I would like to use pure dygraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems is that typescript doesn't know the types and you also need to import what you use `Dygraph` from the module `dygraphs`. Try to install the typing files:

`npm install --save-dev @types/dygraphs`

and in your file:

```
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';

... 

new Dygraph(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

While I feel I hacked much of this it did get a relevant result. Three instances of dygraphs on the webpage. I initially tried with ng-dygraphs without success so I tried to insert dygraphs without the wrapper using the info at https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs-es6 coupled with the earlier answer **here** from Andrei Tătar.

I did not edit the package.json file as in the Q. The missing piece without the wrapper was to add typings (having already added dygraphs and ng-dygraph and doing this within an angular-cli built project):

```
ng add @types\dygraphs
```

then this code worked

```
<div #graph></div>
```

with the component details (@ViewChild magic from [Creating Angular2 component/directive wrapper for Dygraphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412398/creating-angular2-component-directive-wrapper-for-dygraphs).)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dygraph',
  templateUrl: './dygraph.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dygraph.component.css']
})
export class DygraphComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('graph')
  graphdiv: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit() {
    new Dygraph(this.graphdiv.nativeElement,
      `Date,A,B
      2016/01/01,10,20
      2016/07/01,20,10
      2016/12/31,40,30
      `, {
        fillGraph: true
    });  
  }
```

success with the graphs. So I went back to adding ng-graphs in again. And kept getting the same error so eventually I went in and edited

```
node_modules\ng-dygraphs\ng-dygraphs.es5.js
```

and

```
node_modules\ng-dygraphs\ng-dygraphs.js
```

to include the line:

```
import Dygraph from 'dygraphs';
```

ng-dygraphs then "found" Dygraphs and ... I got three trends that way too.

My app.component.html file has three of hence the three trends.

```
<app-dygraph></app-dygraph>
<app-dygraph></app-dygraph>
<app-dygraph></app-dygraph>
```

Disclaimer: I just hacked this until it worked for me. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install both dygraphs and types/dygraphs package into your Angular Project

`npm i dygraphs --save
 npm i @types/dygraphs --save`

After that just write this in the component you are using the Dygraphs

```
declare var Dygraph:any;
```

It worked out for me. It didn't showed me any errors while using them. I was working with Angular 8.